# csv file to json linux

Tags: json, linux, csv

I have a file like this in csv which was downloaded from salesforce:

```
"ID","Name","Email"
"1","AAAA","AA@AAA.COM"
"1","AAAA","BB@AAA.COM"
"1","AAAA","CC@CCC.COM"
"2","NNN","NN@NNN.NN"
"3","EEE","CC@WWW.WW"
"3","EEE","DD@OOO.CV"
```

I need to transform that file into json like this :

```
[    
 {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "AAAA",
    "email": "AA@AAA.COM" ,"BB@AAA.COM","CC@CCC.COM"
  },    
 {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "NNN",
    "email": "NN@NNN.NN"
  },
 {
    "Id": "3",
    "Name": "EEE",
    "email": "CC@WWW.WW" ,"DD@OOO.CV"
  },
]
```

I need to identify which lines have same ID and Name then concatenate the email into same line. The output should be a json file.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: The output is not a JSON. Maybe you want an array of emails under `"email":`?

Comment: Here is the command , assuming the file is rep2.tx2 :

cat rep2.txt | tail -n +2 | head -n -8 | sed 's/"//g' | jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output 'split("\n")  | map(split(",")) | map({"ianaId": .[0],"registrar": .[1],"email": .[2]})'

the head and tail is only because the report has some lines at top and bottom that we need to omit.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Text::CSV_XS qw{ csv };

my %by_id;
my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({binary => 1});
open my $fh, '<', shift or die $!;

$csv->getline($fh); # Skip header
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my ($id, $name, $email) = @$row;
    $by_id{$id}{Id} = $id;
    $by_id{$id}{Name} = $name;
    push @{ $by_id{$id}{email} }, $email;
}

my $json = 'JSON'->new->canonical;
print $json->encode([map $by_id{$_}, sort { $a <=> $b } keys %by_id]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Any suggestion for improving the jq command to get the result or using python, Simply because I had to install many perl modulea to get it work ...

Comment: Here is a new improvement but still not able to get the result maybe you can help :
gawkscript : 
BEGIN {FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{ k=$1 FS $2; a[k] = (k in a)? a[k] FS $3 : $3 } 
END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }

Then :  cat rep222.txt|tail -n +2 | gawk -f gawkscript  (To transform the initial report from sales force into lines with multiple emails) the issue is this generate file with space not ","  any help

Comment: When I changed the column names from Id to ianaId and Name to registrar I don't get the proper result. the JSON file start with email rather then ianaId ??, any help

Comment: Also the file has some empty values for ianaId which then gives this error Argument "" isn't numeric in sort at psc1.perl line 22, <$fh> line 30.

Comment: The JSON file is used with curl to be sent to API, however the API does not accept the [] , the exact syntax should be : 
 {
        "ianaId": 940,
        "registrar": "name-of-registrar-5",
        "email": "email-1@registrar.com,email-1@registrar.com"
    }

Comment: If you need a solution to a different question, ask a new question.